# Why I got an error in Web Service "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"..?

Tags: objective-c, xml, xcode

Thanks in Advance

When I m trying to call a webservice getting error with "exc_bad_access". I've put my code below.

This is small part where I got an error:

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);

    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",theXML);

    [theXML release];

    if( xmlParser )

    {

        [xmlParser release];

        }

    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];     <--- Error here.

    [xmlParser setDelegate:self];

    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];

    [xmlParser parse];

    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];

    [connection release];

    [webData release];
}
```

Comment: are you sure its in that line? i see nothing bad with it if you pass NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);

Comment: Where is webdata defined.  It looks as if could be that webdata may have been autoreleased.

Comment: Finally my error solved...! by putting webData=nil; just after release..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add:

```
xmlParser = nil;
```

Right after

```
[xmlParser release];
```

Comment: It's really work brother and lott of thanks but in my case after getting result it will crash immediately.Result will be displayed in output window but simulator will crash after.Reply

Comment: 2011-12-03 12:29:22.111 testws[2149:f803] -[NSXMLParser length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68c8c70
2011-12-03 12:29:22.112 testws[2149:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSXMLParser length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68c8c70'

Comment: d.lebedev..error solved by fixing webData=nil; after [webData release];..Thanks